# Does Pharo support home (~) as part of a path?

Tags: path, filepath, pharo

I am trying to use a path relative to home directory (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in Pharo 8 but it does not work. For example:

```
'~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' asFileReference exists    ==> false
```

and the path is

```
'~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' asPath      ==> "Path / 'home' / 'ubuntu' / 'stuff' / '~' / '.ssh' / 'id_rsa.pub'"
```

Now, in `String>>asPath` the example says `'~/Desktop' asPath`, so I'm guessing this used to be supported and then the API was changed.

How do I get a full path from something like `'~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'` in pharo?

Answer (score 4):

Pharo supports it in the form of a `FileLocator`:

```
(FileLocator home / '.ssh' / 'id_rsa.pub') fullName "=> '/home/esteban/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a oneliner for going from string with `~` to string with `/home/esteban/`?